# What happend when using kill -9 to kill a thread

Tags: linux, multithreading

Will the thread to be killed handle some signals and do something?

Answer (score 0):

This is what the manual page of kill says:

> kill - send a signal to a process

kill command applies for the whole process, not to one thread.
It is not possible to send a kill signal to a particular thread, at least not from the outside. A thread is inside a process and thus can't be killed from outside. There is a function [pthread_kill()](https://linux.die.net/man/3/pthread_kill) which sends the signal to a thread in the same process as the caller.